# How to stop Windows 10 from constantly overwriting the bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

After switching to legacy boot and turning secure booting off I could trivially install ubuntu on my new Yoga 510 for dual booting. However (and I have now reinstalled grub from the ubuntu live image twice) booting windows always replaces something and the bootmanager is gone afterwards.

Can somebody tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Where did you installed Grub (Ubuntu's bootloader )? For a correct installation Grub is supposed to lead the booting process.

Comment: @ipselute How do I find out? I simply installed with grub-install. I assumed everything was correct because it works as long as I don't boot windows.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu in Legacy/BIOS/CSM, and then boot Windows in UEFI, system switches to UEFI and will not default boot BIOS. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I confirm: I encountered one laptop in the past that would overwrite the GRUB EFI file with a backup copy of the Windows EFI file at every boot, no matter what. IIRC it was a Lenovo. The solution was to overwrite the backup copy with a copy of rEFInd, **after** renaming the Windows bootloader to something else.

Comment: @Warkwark, please update your question with the output of `ls /boot/EFI` after installing Ubuntu and then another time doing it from a liveCD but after Windows has overwritten GRUB.

Comment: @oldfred that sounds interesting. Here is the report: http://paste2.org/0FN7ydOt

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Hm...so when I boot from a USB stick there is no /boot/efi. I switched to legacy boot in the BIOS. When I mount /dev/sda1 there is an EFI directory with Boot, Microsoft and ubuntu subdirectories. Do you mean that?

Comment: You have both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. Your ESP - efi system partition shows both folders & files for Windows & Ubuntu boot. Usually the ESP is not mounted, or is mounted once booted at /boot/efi and is EFI/ubuntu, so full path is /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu.  But you left Windows fast start up on. That must be off. "The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state."  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the link. I turned fastboot off but it didn't help. I still get windows every time after I booted into windows once. Any other ideas?

Comment: Found another setting in the bios which had some sort of efi boot order where  windows was before ubuntu. Changed it and it works now.

Comment: So your question should be updated. Your Windows system was not overwriting stuff, you simply had to change the boot order in the BIOS. :) Also you should post a self-answer explaining what you did. If you can, include a picture as well.

Comment: Probably the OP has already found a solution but for the benefit of others some good solutions are outlined in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine I implemented the solution outlined by Karlovsky120 and so far had no issues.

Comment: @gdesilva Although this is not clear from the questions. The main issue here was actually fast-boot.